# Login / register form doesnt send e confirmation email

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, phpmailer

i read a tutorial about login And registration forms And downloaded And uploaden The source code to my website from:

https://github.com/daveismyname/loginregister

But it doesnt send The email!, please help

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: Don't use that example. It's very out of date and will teach you some bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**

Also check php.ini file on your server. Add following code and then try

Add following code in php.ini for mail (using sendmail)

```
[mail function]
; Setup for Linux systems
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
sendmail_from = me@myserver.com
```

For SMTP Configuration php.ini :

```
[mail function]
; Setup for Windows systems
SMTP = smtp.my.isp.net
sendmail_from = me@myserver.com
```

Comment: php.ini?, I use byethost to host where's php.ini?

Comment: d u have access to cpanel ? folders on server ?

Comment: He's already using PHPMailer, and don't link to obsolete sources.